# opencart 2.0 вопрос про адреса

Tags: opencart

Здравствуйте. Делаю вывод адресов:

> $this->model_account_address->getAddresses()

там сейчаc 2 адреса Как можно узнать который из них основной?

Comment: Спросите того кто эти адреса вводил, который для него из них главный.Ну или заглядывать в поля и смотреть где там стоит address_1,address_2.Ну а по логике первый и есть главный 
https://github.com/Dreamvention/2_d_quickcheckout_lite/blob/master/catalog/model/d_quickcheckout/address.php

Comment: В массиве не указан текущий адрес, там все прямо подряд выводит.

Comment: $address_id = $this->customer->getAddressId();
$this->load->model('account/address');
$address = $this->model_account_address->getAddress($address_id);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    foreach($this->model_account_address->getAddresses() as $k => $v){
        if($k == $this->customer->getAddressId()){
            print_r($v);            
        }
    }
```

вывод текущий адрес

Answer (score 2):

Нашел, основной адрес хранится в: `$this->customer->getAddressId()`